# Groups and Roles in cloudfoundry UAA

Tags: cloudfoundry-uaa

In our system we are currently using UAA for user authentication. There is also a need to put in place access control for resources. A resource is defined as a runtime entity created by user. The access to the resource is dependent on which group he belongs too. In order to achieve that I want to create custom groups and roles in UAA and attach privileges to the groups and roles. Is there provision to add custom groups and roles in UAA? If not how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can always add custom groups with Rest APIs or commands.
Here is the command line example.

-Get the token for an admin client
`uaac token client get admin -s adminsecret`

-Create the group
`uaac group add custom.group`

-Add a user to the group
`uaac member add custom.group user1`

The user1 token will start showing the custom.group in its scope list.
You must of course also need to add the custom.group entry in the scope of the client you are requesting token with. If the client does not have it in its scope list, the user1 token returned will also not show the custom.group in its scope.